# Magento 2 PayPal Payflow Pro Testing

Tags: magento, paypal, magento2, payflowpro

I am running Magento 2.2.3. We are having a really strange issue where random customers will enter their billing information and get a "No such entity with cartID” error.

After extensive searching, I've not found any solution to the problem. Some solutions are available when the Magento 2 store is a multistore. Ours is not.

In my attempt to find a solution, we are setting up a test sandbox account for PayPal PayFlow Pro (our merchant) and run multiple orders to see if we can recreate the error with any consistency.

When placing an order on the test account, we get an error of "transaction has been declined". Yet, in PayPal Manager, the charge shows up as approved and successful.

Does anyone have ideas on solutions to either part of this problem?

Comment: You can try to enable logs first in magento PayPal pro module and check is anything there.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest updating to 2.2.6 since there have been some changes to the PayPal module. Also make sure you get your test CC and data from this address : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#testing-transactions and not the PayPal CC Generator since they will not work with PayFlow.

Also, in M2, you should see two transactions per order, one with the amount of 0$ that will request the token and then the second one with the actual amount of the order that will be charged to the card.

Read this : https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/payment/paypal-payflow-pro.html and this https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/how-do-i-integrate-payflow-pro-with-magento-2.0-ts2093 to make sure you are configured properly.

If that does not fix it, are you seeing one or two transactions in the PayPal Manager and what is the amount of the transactions.

Also, you should add a print screen or the exact error details/number.